# In C# and WPF, can you bind an element of an array to an objects property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

For example, is it possible to bind a Textblock's Text property to an element Name[2] of type String?

Comment: Do you mean how to bind Name[2] to the control property declaretively in XAML?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean. Right now, though, the binding is working but the target control does not get updated when the source variable is changed. I'm stumped

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by saying:*an element Name[2] of type String*, so here are two possible solutions to your problem: Array1 and String1. Array1 show bow to bind to element of an array and String1 shows how to display one single character in a string.

CODE:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Array array1 = new[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
    public Array Array1 { get { return array1; } }

    public string string1 = "string";
    public string String1 { get { return string1; } }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Array1[0]}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Array1[2]}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding String1[0]}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding String1[1]}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works except that updating the source doesn't update the target control. I've tried everything and it isn't working so far. Should I be using an ObservableCollection?

Comment: Since this comment doesn't allow I've posted another answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Following is the XAML approach. 
It is advisable to bind to an Observable collection if you want to update the UI automatically when the value changes.

```
public class DataStub
{
    public Array SomeNorthEasternStates
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { "NH", "VT", "CT", "MA", "ME" };      
        }
    }
}
```

XAML: Assuming the DataContext is set correctly:

```
<TextBox Margin="5" Text="{Binding SomeNorthEasternStates[3], Mode=Default}"/>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using the methods of the `Array` class instead of doing simply `var testArray = new string[5]; testarray[0] = "NY"; ...`.

Comment: @Heinzi - Or var testArray = new [] { "NH", "VT", "CT", "MA", "ME" }; (NY and NJ aren't in New England) :)

Comment: @John Bowen. My bad. Changed the name.

Comment: @Heinzi. No specific reason. See Edit. 7 hrs later with some sleep and coffee I am wondering why I did it that way. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've added a button in xaml and subscribed "click" event.

Here is C# code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Array array1 = new[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
    public Array Array1 { get { return array1; } }


    public string string1 = "string";
    public string String1
    {
        get { return string1; }
        set
        {
            string1 = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("String1"));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        array1.SetValue("another test", 0); 
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Array1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. ObservableCollection implements those features as well and is working perfectly. I appreciate your help klm_.

Answer (score 3):

Use ObservableCollection instead:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" });

public ObservableCollection<string> MyItems
{
    get { return _myItems; }
    set { _myItems = value; }
}
```

Xaml

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyItems[0]}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyItems[2]}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyItems[0]}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyItems[1]}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you mean that if we can bind array item with textBox then, yes

```
 <TextBox Margin="10" Text="{Binding Name[2], Mode=Default}"  Name="textBox1"/>
```

Comment: TextBox doesn't have a Content property.