# Making a binding update from an array

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, arrays, data-binding

I'm not sure if the array is really the issue here but I have a rectangle which I want to move from one side of the window to the other when the MouseUp event is raised. I have this rectangle bound to an array element and the MouseUp event handler method changes the value of that array. I know the handler method works as it can pull up a message box fine, just not switch the position of the rectangle.

Note: The array is necessary, this is just code for testing these concepts, not my actual project.

Also the simplest method to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

C# Code:

```
namespace WPFTestingApplication
{
    public static class GridProperties
    {
        public static int[] gridColumn = { 0 };
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Rect_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            GridProperties.gridColumn[0] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestingApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTestingApplication"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Name="Rect" Grid.Column="{Binding [0], Source={x:Static local:GridProperties.gridColumn}, Mode=OneWay}" Fill="DarkGray" Margin="5" MouseUp="Rect_MouseUp_1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is the problem. You should read up on [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), nothing you bind to will be updated without it.

If you can, change your array to an `ObservableCollection` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for changes to its elements. You can index it just like it's an array.

You may also have issues with storing the property collection in a static class. Static classes and properties don't have property changed notifications. If it's possible for the GridProperties to be a property on the window class that will be easier. Then, set the DataContext of the window to itself.

Something like this works for your example. Can't tell if you have something more complicated in your actual project though.

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> GridProperties { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GridProperties = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        GridProperties.Add(0);
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Rect_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        GridProperties[0] = 1;
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Name="Rect" Grid.Column="{Binding GridProperties[0]}" Fill="DarkGray" Margin="5" MouseUp="Rect_MouseUp_1"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's where we have to put away the Windows Forms mentality (heh). In WPF you need to think about the separation between *functionality* and *appearance*. That is, you allow your code (c#) to determine the functionality aspect, and then do some templating in xaml to give it the appearance.

The functionality you actually want is that of a **Thumb**. A thumb already has the dragging functionality built into it, so you just need to create a template to give it it's appearance.

First take a look at this:

http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/dragging/

I would approach this by creating your own class that derives from thumb like this:

```
// Although the visual template we're applying is a circle,
// the FUNCTIONALITY is primarily that of a thumb. So that's what 
// we'll use. A thumb is essentially a 'draggable thing'.
class DragCircle : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb
{      
    public DragCircle()
    {
        // Thumbs _track_ movement, but they don't actually move. We have to handle this ourselves.
        // We do this by setting the Canvas.Left/Canvas.Top attached properties. Of course, for this
        // to work our DragCircle has to be placed on a Canvas, otherwise there's no-one to read the property.
        // IMPORTANT! In order to read the Canvas position later, it needs to have a record in the WPF 
        // dependency property table. So for now we'll just set it to '0' as a default.
        Canvas.SetLeft (this, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop (this, 0);

        // The drag-delta event occurs when the Thumb is dragged. 'delta' represents "change" just like
        // we all learned in calculus.
        this.DragDelta += new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventHandler(DragCircle_DragDelta);
    }

    void DragCircle_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        // Read the Canvas location from the WPF database.
        Double currentX = Canvas.GetLeft(this);
        Double currentY = Canvas.GetTop(this);

        // Now update the canvas attached properties using the drag-delta ('change in position').
        // Note that Canvas.SetLeft is just a helper function that maps to the attached property: 
        //  this.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, SOME_VALUE);
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, currentX + e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(this, currentY + e.VerticalChange);
    }
}
```

Then just createa template like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="lol:DragCircle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="lol:DragCircle">
                    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now drop it onto a canvas, and you're done.

```
<Canvas>
    <lol:DragCircle Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="200" />
    <lol:DragCircle Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" />
    <lol:DragCircle Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="400" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: That seems overly complicated for what I want to do, I'm just having an issue with the getting the data-binding to update when the array changes.

Comment: Well, let's see if we can't figure out what you're missing. So what are you using your array for? For containing the draggable boxes?

Comment: Array is used for { row, column } coordinates of 8 clickable boxes, its going to be a sliding puzzle game, when i click one it must move to an empty space if it can.

Comment: Oh I get you, you may try taking a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002536/in-c-sharp-and-wpf-can-you-bind-an-element-of-an-array-to-an-objects-property